# FileMaker: Auto-populate a table with data from different tables

Tags: filemaker

I have a FileMaker database. I have three tables - employees, offers and requisitions. I want to bring all the data from these three different tables into one table.

a) I have a unique field (A) common to both the employees and requisitions tables. 
b) I have another unique field common to both the offers and employees table. 
c) The unique fields are unique. They don't repeat in all the three tables.

I want to create a blank table and import all the above said three tables to make it a single table to run my reporting off. Is this something do-able in FileMaker?

Comment: "*I want to bring all the data from these three different tables into one table.*" Why on earth would you want to do such thing?

Comment: I agree with Michael, just use relationships between the tables and build the report based on them.